# Proper pronoun usage: It or That?

Tags: pronouns

Suddenly I came up with this question.

(assuming when somebody and I are talking about mobile phone bandwidth)

my limit is 7gb.
I often exceed it after 15th, then need to pay extra for better bandwidth.

When you say the sentence above, which is correct between the following two?

A: I often exceed it after 15th,...
B: I often exceed that after 15th,...

I would appreciate it, if you could give me any feedback.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to say

> I consume it by 15th and then have to pay extra for better bandwidth

In this case, **it** would be correct.

Comment: Apparently, I should have use "by" rather than "after".. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: If you think I answered your question, please mark it as the answer :)